# What am I doing wrong, how the total price has not changed?

Tags: android

I have been learning android for less than a month. I am worried about how to accumulate "+" and "-" and medium and large to affect the total price.
I will only do the total number of cups for "+" and "-"，and the total price of medium and large.
When I press button3 to calculate the total price
, I automatically quit android. Which step did I take? Please instruct me!!

If you do not rely on the button to calculate the total amount, how do  rely on the checkbox selection and "+" and "-" to directly change the total price?

checkBox2 is medium
checkBox is large 
imageButton and  imageButton6 is "-" "+"
button3 is total price

```
             money = new OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                  public void onClick(View v) {
                       switch (v.getId()) 
                       {
                        case R.id.checkBox2: {textView8.setText( "45" );
              counter = Integer.parseInt( textView8.getText().toString());
                    }
                        break;
                    case R.id.checkBox: {
                        textView8.setText("80");
                        counter=Integer.parseInt(textView8.getText().toString());
                        break; }
                    case R.id.checkBox3:
                        {
                            textView8.setText("");
                        break; }
                }
            }
        };
    }
    OnClickListener AddandLess = new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            switch (v.getId()) {
                case R.id.imageButton: {
                    if (count > 0) {
                        count--;
                        textView.setText( "" + count );
                    }
                }
                break;
                case R.id.imageButton6: {
                    if (count < max) {
                        count++;
                        textView.setText( "" + count );
                    }
                }
                break;

            }
            button3.setOnClickListener( new OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    //String str="Total_price";
                   textView8.setText(counter * count);
                }
            });
        }
    };
```

I hope to influence the total price through the number of cups and the size of the cup，But the implementation is wrong。

This is the error message I have appeared:

Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
failed to make and chown /acct/uid_10058: Read-only file system
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0xa0

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and edit your post to make clear what you already tried and where you Need help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the second time I saw you posting, your code is very Poor readability, 
it is difficult for others to understand certain paragraphs or variable names.

Second, you should attach your error log to make it easier for others to help you.

I think your mistake is here:

```
textView8.setText(counter * count);
```

setText should not be brought into the expression, the correct way to use it is

`setText("String");`

if you want to bring the number into a textview :

```java
int TotalPrice =counter * count;
String strTotalPrice =String.valueOf(TotalPrice);
textView8.setText(strTotalPrice);

or
textView8.setText(String.valueOf(TotalPrice));
```

Comment: Sorry, I will improve.

Comment: @Xun Zheng Chi  I have edited the answer. If it is useful please let me know and mark it as the answer thanks.

Comment: I typed in code, but when I type tostring after TotalPrice it warns "Cannot resolve symbol 'tostring'.

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the OnClickListeners `money`and `AddAndLess` to the parent Layout(Constraint/LinearLayout). Then,this may work. Please format your code (ie: meaningful variable names) for better understanding.

Comment: Thanks, I have rectified the code variable and added OnClicklisteners.